# Mocking a void method with setters and getters

Tags: mockito

I have a code to mock

```
activeData.setContent(taskModel.getSelectedLib)
```

Setters and getter are long, it's a void method so I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: So, what exactly are you wanting to mock? What would be your mock objects? activeData? taskModel? Or both?

Comment: Both of them have to be mocked

Answer (score 0):

Mocking `taskModel.getSelectedLib()` is pretty straight-forward since it returns a value. You can do that by putting the following at the beginning of your test:

`when(mockTaskModel.getSelectedLib()).thenReturn(aLib);`

There is no point in mocking the setContent method though, since it does not return anything. The best thing you can do is verify that the method was called, if you are trying to test that.

Put this line at the END of your test.

`verify(mockActiveData, times(1)).setContent(anyLong());`

Comment: Thanks, but perhaps I thought this was giving the error but it's this line which gives an error

productCountedList.add(activeData);

Can you help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

You should not mock values, instead you may want to have builders to make those object fast.